# Configure private network with static IP for Snappy on Vagrant

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-core, vagrant

I am trying to run Vagrant box ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-stable with two adapters NAT and Host-Only but that does not work with this config:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-stable"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, id: 'ssh', auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10", auto_correct: false
  config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
  config.ssh.host = "192.168.33.10"
end
```

Result:

```
> vagrant destroy --force; vagrant up 
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-stable'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: test_default_8376498
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 192.168.33.10:2222
    default: SSH username: ubuntu
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Host appears down. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Host appears down. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Host appears down. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a vagrant image directly available so that you don't have to jump into those hurdles!

If you download and install the image we present you in https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#vagrant, you can simply connect to your vagrant image through `vagrant ssh` once the image is started.

Comment: But I still need to create a host-only adapter to have a static ip to vagrant. I am using the same box you recommended on that link.